# Gmail signature retrieve with PHP cURL - Invalid Token 401

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to build a GET/POST with cURL in PHP to retrieve and update Gmail signatures.
I'm using a older PHP 5.3  server for testing and PHP libraries v.1 due to server limitation.
I'm able to retrieve data from Directory and Gmail api, by using the libraries, but i need GET/POST for signature according to the docs

```
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#api_operations
```

The login part is handled by GooglePlus.
this is the POST for refreshing the token. There are some vardumps around because i can't SSH to the server, or use xdebug.

```
function getToken() {
    $curl =  curl_init();
    $url ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

    $ses = json_decode($_SESSION['token'],true);
    $opt =array(
        "client_id" =>"************************",
        "client_secret" =>"********************",
        "grant_type" =>"refresh_token",
        "refresh_token" =>"$ses[refresh_token]"
        );      
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'OPT';
    print_r ($opt);
    echo '</pre>';
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$opt);
    $newtok =curl_exec($curl);
    echo'<pre>';
    echo 'New Token';        
    echo('getToken output'.var_dump($newtok).'<br>');
    echo '</pre>';
    curl_close($curl);
    return $newtok;

}
```

And the GET PART

```
function httpGet($url) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])  && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
     try { 
   $auth_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $auth_token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Old tekon';
    var_dump($auth_token);
    echo '</pre>';
    $ch =curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $toknew =  getToken();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.($toknew).''));
   $output =  curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
     }catch (Exception $e) {
         print_r($e);
     }

   echo('httpGet var dump'.var_dump($output).'<br>');
        }
   }
```

i'm calling the function like this

```
echo httpGet("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/mydomain.com/my.user/signature");
```

According to the var_dumps the token i get with getToken() is different from the one i get with google login but i think i'm using it wrong or i misunderstood what token i actully need.

EDIT.
After replacing

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.($toknew).''));
```

with

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Authorization: Bearer ya29.XXXXX(acces token)'));
```

i now get something like

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/my.domain/my.user/signature2016-03-08T15:09:50.799Z
```

No ideea how to parse the results yet :|